# How to perform a search in multivalued Integer field in solr

Tags: d

for example,My multivalued field contains (1,2,3).

If  i search for 1 or(1,2) or (2,3) or (1,3) or 2 or 3 or  or (1,2,3) the above result should come.

How to define this integer multivalued field.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well your question - you simply want a Set and a way to check whether a given set is a subset of the original set. More about this you can find on [this Wikipedia page (Set theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).

One of ways to implement this is to use the RedBlackTree from the stardard D runtime: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_container.html#.RedBlackTree .